# min-height/min-width doesn't respect box-sizing in some browsers

Tags: html, css, overflow

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/vrgT3/5/

I made a `250x250px` parent div with `overflow: auto;` so scrollbars appear when the content overflows the box. I have set a blue background to make it clear when the parent is visible.

Inside the parent is a child div with red background for visibility. It has `8px` black borders and `box-sizing: border-box;` so padding and borders are included in computing the size of the box. The child div is set to `min-height: 100%` and `min-width: 100%`.

**Expected result:** Child div should be the exact same size as the parent, so no blue is shown and no scrollbars appear. The computed box size (content+padding+borders) should be `250x250px`. There should be `8px` black borders inlaying this, leaving a `234x234px` red region.

**Works with:**

- Midori 4.1 Ubuntu
- Chromium 16 Ubuntu
- Opera 11.61 Ubuntu

**Issues with:**

- IE 8 WinXP: Horizontal and vertical scrollbars appear. The content is `249x266px` with `8px` borders giving a computed box size of `265x282px`.
- Firefox 3.6 WinXP: Vertical scrollbar appears. The content is `217x250px` and computed box size is `233x266px`.
- Firefox 10 Ubuntu: Vertical scrollbar appears, content is `221x250px`, computed box size is `237x266px`.

I have checked caniuse.com and it appears that at least the browsers in question support the required `min-height`, `min-width`, and `box-sizing`. What gives?

**Solution:** As Marat suggested, this is indeed a browser bug. I've resolved a workaround utilizing JavaScript to add padding/margins to correct for differences in offsetWidth/Height. See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/vrgT3/8/

Comment: IE8 has had long-known issues with min/max width/height and overflow; box sizing is not relevant. As for the others...

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response! I have tried removing the `overflow` property (thus falling back to `overflow: visible`) and I am still getting incorrect sizes in both IE and FF. The purpose of `box-sizing` is to include the large borders in the `min-*: 100%`. This works as expected with Midori, Opera, and Chromium.

Comment: See also http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/ ("Min/Max" section below the "Support" section)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is unfortunate bug of Firefox (see [bug 308801](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=308801)) and IE8 (IE9 works correctly).

The bug is fixed in Firefox 17+.

Comment: Ah, so it is. But seriously, we're at Firefox 10 with nearly 7 year old bugs? Any known workarounds?

Comment: Workaround is to use extra wrapper. And then set `border` and `padding` for child block without `min-height`, and set `min-height` for parent block of the child block.

Comment: By the way, if the bug is important for you, consider voting for its fixing on the page of the bug. The more votes the bug has, the more chances it will be fixed soon. For example, for bug [401322](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=401322), it was enough to have 96 votes for the bug to get high priority for it, and it has been fixed quite quickly (~3,5 months after reporting).

Comment: I still can't seem to get an example working with all the browsers I listed. I'll post another example when I get home if no one else can figure it out.

Comment: This seems to work for this example, but does it allow for percentage based sizes?

Comment: I've finally worked out a solution which is independent of the parent's dimensions. Uses offsetHeight and offsetWidth to correct for error in problematic browsers. View it here: http://jsfiddle.net/vrgT3/8/

Comment: You technically answered my question "What gives?" and I've found a work around so I'll go ahead and close this question. Thanks for the tip off about the bug!