# How to make the height of two side-by-side elements extend to the remaining browser height?

Tags: css, jquery-ui

In this example, http://jsfiddle.net/mnXH9/, the height of the `content-display` element and the height of the `nav-menu-container` are fixed.

How do I make the height of the  `content-display` and `nav-menu-container` elements extend to the remaining height of the browser window as the browser height is being adjusted by a user provided the height in the browser window is greater than 400px (The height of the header plus the nav-menu-container)?

I would like for the scrollbar to be inside the `nav-menu-content` element if the total height in the browser is greater than the sum of the height of the header (100px) and the `nav-menu-container` element (300px).

If the browser window's height is less than 400px then a scrollbar would appear in the browser window to allow scrolling throughout the 100px header and the 300px min-height of the below elements.

## EDIT

Attached are photoshopped mockups of what the jsfiddle should look like.

[image: What tab 1 should look like when the browser height is less than 400px]

*tab 1 when the browser height is less than 400px*

[image: What tab 1 should look like when the browser height is greater than 400px]

*tab 1 when the browser height is greater than 400px*

[image: What tab 2 should look like when the browser height is less than 400px]

*tab 2 when the browser height is less than 400px*

[image: What tab 2 should look like when the browser height is greater than 400px]

*tab 2 when the browser height is greater than 400px*

## EDIT

[image]

*tab 2 of http://jsfiddle.net/mnXH9/25/show/*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT--switched fiddle versions to one working better based off comments and noted IE8.**

[View a full screen version here](http://jsfiddle.net/mnXH9/25/show/) ([view css here](http://jsfiddle.net/mnXH9/25/)). This uses `@media` queries and some other CSS3, so it will not work on older browsers, but I believe it does exactly what you requested. I reset the two columns to be `position: absolute` to achieve this. Some javascript to check for height could be used to fix older browsers if necessary.

IE8 (if you care) needs to also have the `overflow: auto` set on the `#tabs` (I removed it from that to the `.panel` inside for better effects on other browsers).

Comment: Thanks Scott! it does exactly what I needed. just a quick one, my IDE is throwing a warning for the `and` keyword in `@media screen and (min-height: 400px)` saying `Unexpected symbol(s) found: "and"`, is there an alternative syntax to this statement?

Comment: That is the only syntax I know of. [See w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/CR-css3-mediaqueries-20100727/#media0). At least it is just a "warning."

Comment: Ah ty, one final question, there's a scrollbar always on the right if you use chrome.  Do you know how to get around that?

Comment: Try adding the `html` element to the `@media` query that currently sets `overflow-y: hidden` on just the `body`. It could be Chrome is still putting up a scroll for that (I cannot test Chrome at the moment).

Comment: Thanks again Scott, I just tried that, unfortunately the bottom 100px or so are being cut off when I do `@media screen and (min-height: 0) {
    html, body {
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }
}`

Comment: @LedZeppelin--That's no good :-). I just tested on Chrome (Win 7; version 17.0.963.79 m) and did not see the scroll bar you refer to previously. What version are you on?

Comment: Hi scott, I'm using ver 17 as well. Can you view **tab 2** in chrome 17.0 and tell me if the bottom gets cut off? http://jsfiddle.net/mnXH9/22/show/

Comment: Yes, it was. The `#tab` needed the `height` changed to `min-height` and the `#content-display` needed the `box-sizing` set also. I believe [this version is improved](http://jsfiddle.net/mnXH9/23/show/)... except I just noticed it is putting a scroll on tab one now...

Comment: @LedZeppelin--my comment above has a link that works for Chrome, but Firefox is now adding the scroll on tab one. There seems to be a bug in how it is implementing `min-height` in relation to `-moz-box-sizing`. [See this demo in Firefox](http://jsfiddle.net/LTamp/7/).

Comment: Thanks again, actually tabs 2 and 3 still get cut off at the bottom in chrome http://jsfiddle.net/mnXH9/23/show/ if the browser height is small.  I can live without the 400px browser min-height.  IE `@media screen and (min-height: 0) {
    html, body {
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }
}`.  Is there any way we can get cross-browser support for 0 min-height?

Comment: @LedZeppelin--The [FF thing with min-height/box-sizing is a bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508262/min-height-min-width-doesnt-respect-box-sizing-in-some-browsers). Not sure what you mean by "cutoff". I can scroll the whole of tab 2-3 (the border is cut off until you scroll all the way down, but that is because the border is at the bottom of the scrollable div. You might need to nest another div to avoid that. I don't understand your question (or point) in 0 min-height.

Comment: @LedZeppelin--okay, I see the cutoff (less than 400px on Chrome, body scrolled up, but still not scrolling fully).

Comment: @LedZeppelin--[look at this one](http://jsfiddle.net/mnXH9/25/show/). I only see a "cutoff" in Chrome when my Norton Identity safe has a pop-down that comes from the top, which messes with me being able to scroll all the way. With that closed, I get a full scroll.

Comment: Thanks so much, so I've edited the original post with a screenshot of what tab 2 `http://jsfiddle.net/mnXH9/25/show/` looks like on my win7 chrome 17.0.  That's what I mean by the bottom being cutoff.  The browser window ends without displaying the bottom portion of the contents of the page.

Comment: @LedZeppelin--Thanks for the screen shot. I do not experience that on my Win7 Chrome 17.0.963.79. The bottom of the scroll bar (with the down pointing arrow) is fully visible on my screen. That is quit a mystery.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Scott.  It turns out I have a toolbar installed on chrome that pushes everything down.  You should put your email address or your website in your profile.  I know some times employers looks for knowledgeable people like you to contact and hire =).

Comment: @LedZeppelin--I'm glad that was the issue. Thanks for bounty and the complement about hiring, but web design is really more a "hobby" for me. My professional pursuit resides in a different field.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [faux columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/) to accomplish equivalent height on tab container and right nav - would be simpler than mocking around with manual height settings. That would also make them appear to extend to the entire browser height.

Answer (score -2):

```
<style>
html {
height: 100%;
}
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100%;
}
#container {margin:auto; height:100%; width: 500px;}
#header {top:0px;background-color: pink; height:100px; border-bottom: none; z-index:50}
#content-display {position:relative; width: 300px; height:100%; float: left; z-index:-1;}
#nav-menu-container {position:relative; bottom:43px;padding-top:50px;left:300px; width:200px; height:100%; background:lightblue; z-index:-1;}
#nav-menu-content { width: 100px; margin-left:50px; margin-top:43px;height:300px; background:greenyellow;}
#tabs ul li a {font-family: Arial,Helvetica,Verdana,sans-serif; font-size: 13px;} /*Tab title text*/
#tabs {height:100%;}
.panel{height:218px; overflow: auto;}
</style>
```

Comment: Sorry this doesn't extend both of the side-by-side elements to the bottom of the browser if the browser height is greater than 400px

Comment: sorry, thought you just wanted one, let me fix it

Comment: Your edit doesn't fix it.  I don't think you understood my question.

Comment: I haven't edited it. Still working on it, give me a few mins.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks.  If you don't mind, can you update the jsfiddle?

Comment: If I ever get this working sure, the trouble is the margins. Because if the 100% height attribute the nav bar becomes longer than the content by of course 100px...But I have nothing better to do...so I will figure it out.

Comment: Lol, I appreciate it.  This is a really difficult one to solve.  I'll check this in a few hours.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8998/discussion-between-iwishiwasacodemonkey-and-ledzeppelin)

Comment: This doesn't fix it, the tabs aren't clickable and the two side by side elements extend beyond the remaining browser height