# box-sizing: border-box => for IE8?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, internet-explorer-8

i want `box-sizing: border-box` for `div` tag.

For **Mozila Firefox** i have tried

```
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
```

For **IE(Internet Explorer)** i have tried  both of below alternatively

```
        -ms-box-sizing: border-box; 
            box-sizing: border-box;
```

but it couldn't works in **IE(Internet Explorer)**.
Though i have apply   `box-sizing: border-box;` for **Internet Explorer** it adds with of border and padding in width of element. why does it happen?

what should be the problem? please help and sugest me.

**NOTE:** i am using **Internet Explorer8** and **Windows7 ultimate**

**PAGE CODE:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MainPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="MainPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=8"/>

    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        *
        {
            box-sizing: border-box; /*it gives error:Validation (CSS 2.1): 'box-sizing' is not a known CSS property name. */
            -ms-box-sizing: border-box; 
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
            }
        body
        {
            background: lightblue;
            color: #000000;
            font-family: Trebuchet MS, Arial, Times New Roman;
            font-size: 12px;
        }
        #header
        {
            background: #838283;
            height: 200px;
            width: 1200px;
        }
        #wrapper
        {
            background: #FFFFFF;
            margin: 0px auto;
            width: 1200px;
            height: 1024px;
        }
        #navigation
        {
            background: #a2a2a2;
            float: left;


            margin: 0px 0px;
            width: 1200px;
            height: 25px;
            padding: 3px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <h1>
                Header goes here</h1>
            <br />
            <h2 style="font-size: 60px;">
                ST ERP by Shanti Technology</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="navigation">
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The validation error is irrelevant - `box-sizing` is part of CSS3, not CSS2.1. If you really care about validation, notice that the prefixes won't validate against any version of CSS either.

Comment: could i change version of CSS?

Comment: did you check my answer? -ms-box-sizing: border-box; is not needed

Comment: Visual Studio lets you validate against CSS3. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931801/is-it-possible-to-change-css-validation-scheme-in-vs2010 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810401/css-3-0-in-visual-studio-2010

Comment: Windows 7 and IE8.  Yikes.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

IE8 supports the unprefixed version of `box-sizing`, but as with all "new" CSS features it only does so in standards mode. `-ms-box-sizing` has never been used by any version of IE.

Make sure your page has a doctype declaration to trigger standards mode in browsers. You should also place your unprefixed `box-sizing` *after* all the prefixes, not *before* them, and get rid of `-ms-box-sizing` as it's really not needed.

Comment: this is the doctype declared on my page==>  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: Can I see your page? There must be something else causing the issue.

Comment: See code ...and for `navigation` id i have applied `padding: 3px;` which add into the width of the element on which i applied `navigation` id NOTE: this issue in IE8.

Comment: I don't see any `box-sizing` in your code. I've already mentioned that IE8 supports the unprefixed version - have you tried placing it in your actual code to see if it works?

Comment: @BoltClock it seems like IE is having trouble with apply `box-sizing: border-box;` correctly. see this example on a modern browser & then on IE8 http://jsbin.com/nuzayivuroyu/2/edit?html,css,output . EDIT: it seems to be because of the `min-width` property, if you change it by `with`, it then works fine in IE8, see http://jsbin.com/vapasehiziku/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: @Adrien Be: How did you even manage to get JS Bin to work on IE8?

Comment: @BoltClock oh oh, actually I tested those example on jsBin *without* the CSS & HTML panel shown. So the URLs become  jsbin.com/nuzayivuroyu/2/ and jsbin.com/vapasehiziku/1/

Comment: @Adrien Be: Ah. I just noticed the arrow at the corner of the preview pane which takes me to that those URLs.

Comment: Warning: `min-width` & `max-width` not working with `box-sizing: border-box;` is a known bug in IE8 and Firefox 16&below. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508262/min-height-min-width-doesnt-respect-box-sizing-in-some-browsers

Comment: @Adrien Be: Ha, I commented on that question before... I should have known better. Thanks for your findings.

Comment: @BoltClock hehe, I guess we humans have a finite memory :) You're welcome! maybe you can update your answer?

Answer (score 10):

If you are using min-width or min-height as well, box-sizing will be stuck as "content-box" in IE8 (Standards mode), i.e. specifying border-box will have no effect.

Comment: This is the answer that solved my issue - min-height on my elements was causing border-box to fail in IE8. Hopefully this answer will be voted up in due course as it deserves more prominence (for those of us who are still saddled with IE8 support at least...)

Answer (score 5):

IE8+ supports box-sizing.

**Support:**

```
    Opera 8.5+  : box-sizing
    Firefox 1+  : -moz-box-sizing (still prefixed, though some are pushing to have it unprefixed for [Firefox 29][2]).
    Safari 3    : -webkit-box-sizing (unprefixed in modern versions)
    IE8+        : box-sizing
```

[Please review this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/randeep161/QqHBD/)

Comment: I can't see `box-sizing` in your code.
use `box-sizing: border-box;` in that and try again.

Comment: `box-sizing` property is in CSS3 that why you got the Validation error.

Comment: -1; the claim that the `box-sizing` property is unprefixed in modern versions of Firefox is false, even today. Version 26, the latest version as of the date I'm posting this, still doesn't support the unprefixed `box-sizing` property, a year and a half after this answer was posted.

Comment: @RDX jsFiddle is nice BUT it does not support IE8 (only in draft mode anyway). So for IE8, one might use this http://jsbin.com/nuzayivuroyu/1/ (you could add this link to your answer)

Answer (score 2):

box-sizing supports IE8+

you can see [here](http://www.caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing)

Comment: i got following Error:- `Validation (CSS 2.1): 'box-sizing' is not a known CSS property name`.

Comment: @Pritesh `box-sizing` was not defined in CSS2.1 - http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-ui/#box-sizing.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `box-sizing: border-box;` -

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;

  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
}
```

IE Does not require vendor specific CSS `-ms-box-sizing: border-box;` is not needed

**Fiddle** - http://jsfiddle.net/ctHh3/

Answer (score 0):

put this in your page, problem solved

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
```