# CSS background-size issue in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, css

I have a CSS property `background-size` set to `729px auto;` for a center div for a blue frame,

Here are the results in IE and Firefox (i hide the content with red box):

[image]

Here is the result in Chrome:

[image]

Doees any know if there are special tricks for `background-size` property in Chrome?

Comment: Show us your HTML and CSS please.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use code instead of image?  Problem solved.

http://jsfiddle.net/jDMxJ/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="blue">
    <div class="red">

    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.blue {
    width: 626px;
    height: 326px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.red {
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 3px solid red;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

Comment: My box is made from 3 parts: top center and bottom. Code is not mine i cant overwrite it i just need to fix it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try `box-sizing: border-box;` in your css.

Comment: Note to the OP that this won't work in IE7 if you're planning on supporting it. As for IE8, I recommend reading the chosen answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11608291/box-sizing-border-box-for-ie8

Answer (score 1):

After experiments i found out that Chrome doesn't recognize the `auto` property in here: `729px auto;`

It just cuts it out:

[image]

But when i changed `729px auto;` to `729px 1px;` it WORKED!

I see the blue frame :)

Comment: What about putting 50% to center it then?  To be more precise than just 1px.