# CSS box-sizing inherit cross browsers

Tags: css

When I work on one of my projects I found that the CSS box-sizing property is not automatically inherit in Firefox. Chrome, however, will do the work for you. In my case, it's like:

`<form style="box-sizing:border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;">
  <input id="input1"></input>
  <input id="input2"></input>
</form>`

The box-sizing property is not inherited by the two inputs in firefox.

Am I supposed to add it to the child nodes manually in the future? Is any convention I missed?

Thanks!

Comment: not too sure of what you mean, but form elements depends on browsers and OS, and there are things that you cannot restyle , security reason wich is obvious, and the defaut layout with wich the program(browser,) is build, it explains different padding inside inputs from a browser to another for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`box-sizing`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing0) property is **not** inherited (by default) as you can see from the link - in fact text `<input>` elements have a computed `box-sizing` value of `content-box` (not specifying a type attribute will default to `text`), like *most* elements - the exception is buttons and certain replaced elements like `<meter>`, `<textarea>`, `<progress>` etc. all have a computed `box-sizing` value of `border-box`

I'm not so sure what makes you think Chrome is inheriting the `box-sizing` value from its parent. If you look at the computed styles it clearly says `box-sizing: content-box;`.

http://jsfiddle.net/4ghd6/1/

Comment: Beat me too it.  I will also referenced the [Mozilla Developer Page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fbox-sizing).

Comment: Thanks guys. I was confused by the appearance of elements. These properties are not inherit in all cases. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

You could always try

```
form, form * {box-sizing: border-box;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I normally add it in my CSS - normally right after the reset.

Look at this [Box-sizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11608291/box-sizing-border-box-for-ie8)

> You are missing box-sizing: border-box; -
>
> *{   box-sizing: border-box;
>
> -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;  }
>   IE Does not require vendor specific CSS -ms-box-sizing: border-box; is
>   not needed