# Broken layout with masonry.js but works when adding Foundation 5

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-masonry

**Objective**
To have a functioning "pinterest style" layout.

[image]

**Background**
I previously created a blog concept with Masonry and the layout was pretty smooth. To show how it is supposed to work, I posted [This video on youtube](http://youtu.be/FhAcRMd9a2Q)

I had my [original conceptual demo on codepen](http://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/koFKm) which used Foundation 5.
Then I forked this [broken demo in question - on codepen](http://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/BuCbn).

But it does not work if I remove Foundation 5. But that is really weird because there are no foundation classes anywhere in the HTML.

**Problem**
This should not at all rely on Foundation 5. When I remove the external Foundation 5 file, the containers are floated to either side.

[image]

And the layout goes to single item per column even when the browser window accomodate many more.

[image]

**Current State**

It works but should not rely on Foundation.

Code

**HTML**

```
<div id="gallery-content" class="clearfix">

  <!-- Case 1 -->  
    <div class="case-box item">
      <img src="http://ships.bouwman.com/Planes/Boeing---X-48B.jpg" />
      <div class="case-country country-us"></div>

      <div class="case-description">
        <p>Boeing Blended Wing X-48B</p>
      </div>

      <div class="case-options">
        <a href="#">Details<i class="fa fa-arrows-alt"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div> 

    <!-- many more containers then closed off by #gallery-content div -->
```

**CSS**

The CSS from Foundation 5 coming from CDNJS.

```
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.1.1/css/foundation.min.css
```

And this code that I wrote

```
#gallery-content {
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.item {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
  -webkit-transition: left .4s ease-in-out, top .4s ease-in-out .4s;
  -moz-transition: left .4s ease-in-out, top .4s ease-in-out .4s;
  -ms-transition: left .4s ease-in-out, top .4s ease-in-out .4s;
  -o-transition: left .4s ease-in-out, top .4s ease-in-out .4s;
  transition: left .4s ease-in-out, top .4s ease-in-out .4s;
}

.item img { width: 300px; height: auto; }

.case-box {
  border: #888 1px solid;
  padding-bottom: 72px;
  position: relative;
}

.case-box {
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 2px;
  border-top-left-radius: 2px;
  border-top-right-radius: 2px;
}

.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: ""; display: table; }
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }
.clearfix { *zoom: 1; }
```

**JavaScript**

jQuery

Masonry From CDNJS

```
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.1.2/masonry.pkgd.min.js
```

And this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Initialize Masonry
  $('#gallery-content').masonry({
    columnWidth: 320,
    itemSelector: '.item',
    isFitWidth: true,
    isAnimated: !Modernizr.csstransitions
  }).imagesLoaded(function() {
      $(this).masonry('reload');
    });
  });
```

Live link:
 http://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/BuCbn.

Comment: Presumably there is a reset in foundation that is over-riding browser defaults. Hard to diagnose without a live link

Comment: @user574632 In included like 3 links to it but here it is again. [http://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/BuCbn](http://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/BuCbn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific Foundation CSS that makes your demo work as expected is:

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Without this rule your items are 2 pixels wider, due to their border with being included in the box model calculation, and I expect that's what's breaking the layout.

Here is a fork of your pen, with Foundation removed: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nkmgJ

Comment: Would you happen to have a suggestion how I can edit my question so that others can find this if they have related issues. I dug further into your solution and ran into Paul Irish's blog post about [box sizing](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) and that explains the same issues that I ran into caused by border. It turns out that my problem is neither related to masonry nor foundation in specific.

Answer (score 0):

I accepted the answer by Jonathan because he technically answered it as I originally phrased my question.

However the real issue here is neither with MasonryJS nor does Foundation offer the real solution. The reason **foundation.css** offered the remedy is because of the box sizing reset which was needed because of the `border: #888 1px solid;`.

In a post by Paul Irish, he discusses how to solve this issue with

```
/* apply a natural box layout model to all elements */
*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```

Full post available at: http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Of course there are issues with Internet Explorer versions below 9. You can read more about this at [box-sizing: border-box => for IE8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11608291/box-sizing-border-box-for-ie8)

Chris Coyer discusses box sizing more in depth at http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/.

But the easiest fix to maintain compatibility without relying on this reset was to have just used outline instead of border. You can read more about that at [Difference between outline and border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158515/difference-between-outline-and-border).

So while in my own project I added that reset. I also made sure to change my code from

```
.case-box {
  border: #888 1px solid;
  padding-bottom: 72px;
  position: relative;
}
```

To

```
.case-box {
  outline: #888 1px solid;
  padding-bottom: 72px;
  position: relative;
}
```