# ie8 - border added to max-width when width:100%

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, css

I'm trying to create a box that is responsive in that it uses the combination of max-width and width:100%.

This results in the box having a width that is set by max-width but the box shrinking, rather than overflowing, when its parent container gets too small.

I have this working on ie9 and ff/chrome, but in ie8 standards mode the padding seems to get added to the max-width.

eg:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
</head>
<body>
    <style>
        #test
        {
            border: 1px blue solid;
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 210px;
            display: block;
            height: 30px;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
    </style>


    <span id="test"></span>
</body>
```

This results in a box that is max 210px wide on ie9, firefox, chrome. But in ie8 the border has been added, such that the maxwidth is 212px. Removing the border results in it being 210px again in ie8.

I thought that changing the box-sizing to content-box would help but it doesn't seem to make any difference what the box-sizing is.

Comment: I'm seeing this too, I believe it's a bug in IE8's implementation of box-sizing. If you check the Layout tab in the IE development tools, you'll see that the width of the content box is incorrect.

Comment: `min-width` & `max-width` not working with `box-sizing: border-box;` is a known bug in IE8 and Firefox 16&below. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508262/min-height-min-width-doesnt-respect-box-sizing-in-some-browsers

Answer (score 0):

Try these links to fix any Internet Explorer issues:

(download respond.min.js)
https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond

(download css3-mediaqueries.js)
https://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/

Add this to your `<head>` tag after you download:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="respond.min.js"></script>
```

Try setting max-width to 100% to make the entire box responsive. If you want to change the actual width of the box, you must keep max-width equal to 100% while making the regular width whatever you want.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
</head>
<body>
    <style>
        #test
        {
            border: 1px blue solid;
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 100%;
            display: block;
            height: 30px;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
    </style>


    <span id="test"></span>
</body>
```

Comment: `min-width` & `max-width` not working with `box-sizing: border-box;` is a known bug in IE8 and Firefox 16&below. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508262/min-height-min-width-doesnt-respect-box-sizing-in-some-browsers